# Run Python with package NumPy in Mathematica

Tags: python

For example, if I have a Python script called *simple.py* that contains code as simple as

```
a=1
print(a)
```

then

```
RunProcess[{"python", "E:\\w\\simple.py"}]
```

is OK and gives

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "1

  ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
```

However, if I edit *simple.py* as

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2])
print(a)
```

then

```
RunProcess[{"python", "E:\\w\\simple.py"}]
```

gives

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 1, "StandardOutput" -> "",
 "StandardError" -> "Traceback (most recent call last):

    File \"E:\\w\\WORK\\python\\learning\\simple.py\", line 1, in \
<module>

      import numpy as np

    File \"D:\\IntelPython35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py\"\
, line 158, in <module>

      from . import add_newdocs

    File \"D:\\IntelPython35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\add_newdocs.\
py\", line 13, in <module>

      from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

    File \"D:\\IntelPython35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\lib\\__init__\
.py\", line 8, in <module>

      from .type_check import *

    File \"D:\\IntelPython35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\lib\\type_\
check.py\", line 11, in <module>

      import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

    File \"D:\\IntelPython35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\__init_\
_.py\", line 21, in <module>

      from . import umath

  ImportError: DLL load failed: ÕÒ\.b2»\[Micro]½Ö¸\[Paragraph]¨\
\[Micro]Ä\.b3ÌÐò¡£

  "|>
```

What is wrong? How can I make NumPy work with RunProcess?

---

**Update**

I've tried on a Linux computer. The same Python script works. So is it a problem of why RunProcess doesn't import packages correctly on Windows?

---

**Update**

A workaround.

I uninstalled Intel Python and install [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

Now it is working. Maybe Intel Python misses something in the PATH.

Comment: It's may be an issue with Environment["PATH"] or whatever the windows equivalent is. Check the appropriate environment variable in your shell and in Mathematica. I'm guessing they don't line up.

Comment: Hi, @b3m2a1 Thank you so much for reply. I took your advice. I look into `Environment["PATH"]` and `echo %PATH%`. But they are the same except that `Environment["PATH"]` has 6 more path related to Mathematica than `echo %PATH%`. And here is my system path https://pastebin.com/2Zscj75e

Answer (score 12):

Starting in version 11.2 you may use [`ExternalEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) to run Python from *Mathematica*.  See the [Configure Python for ExternalEvaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) tutorial for setup.

```
session = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python", "ReturnType" -> "Expression"|>]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
res = ExternalEvaluate[session, 
  "import numpy as np; a=np.array([1,2]); a.tolist()"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

End the session with the following.

```
DeleteObject@session
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Edmund. I updated to 11.2 windows. However, even though `FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]` has no problem, `ExternalEvaluate[session, "import numpy as np; a=np.array([1,2]); \
a.tolist()"]` gives error "Import::nopythonevals: No Python external evaluator found. Use RegisterExternalEvaluator to register an external evaluator." and "ExternalEvaluate::interpFail: The result [1, 2] failed to be interpreted as a WL expression. Use "ReturnType"->"String" instead."

Comment: @matheorem Did you configure Python as in the tutorial setup?

Comment: yeah. I think I did. I installed `conda install pyzmq`, also `pip install zmq`

Comment: @matheorem See this post ([155821](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155821)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve your issue, but here are my two cents.

I think it's likely a process environment issue as this works for me on Mac with Mathematica 11.1:

```
RunProcess[{"python3.4", "-i"},
 "StandardOutput",
 "import numpy as np; a=np.array([1,2]); print(a)",
 ProcessEnvironment ->
  <|
   "PATH" -> "/usr/local/bin:" <> Environment["PATH"]
   |>
 ]

"[1 2]
"
```

The different [`ProcessEnvironment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProcessEnvironment.html) is something I always need to run python, since I never bother to use [`SetEnvironment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetEnvironment.html)

Comment: I seems not working for me. I want to know If you don't set ProcessEnvironment, the example will work or not?

Comment: The `ProcessEnvironment` will differ from your machine to mine. I need `/usr/local/bin` because my `python3.4` binary is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/python3.4` You're on windows so the environment will obviously be different. It can find your python distro, but I was guessing the DLL couldn't be loaded because it couldn't be found.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I don't which path to add : )

Comment: @matheorem unfortunately me neither. Hopefully someone with a Windows machine can help you out here.

Comment: I appreaciate your help : )

Answer (score 0):

I installed IntelPython3 on Windows 7 and this worked (with Mathematica 10.1) for me:

```
SetDirectory["\\Users\\gauss\\Documents\\Python Scripts"]
RunProcess[{"C:\\IntelPython3\\python.exe", "simple.py"}]
```

It worked without any adjustment to paths or environment variables.  It also worked without the ".exe" file extension, but it did *not* work without the "C:\\".

The `SetDirectory` was only necessary because I used the filename "simple.py".  It is also possible to use a relative pathname without `SetDirectory`.  That is, this also worked for me as the first command after launching Mathematica:

```
RunProcess[{"C:\\IntelPython3\\python.exe", "Python Scripts\\simple.py"}]
```

In both cases, Python was able to import the NumPy package, create the array and produce the proper output.

**Mathematica environment:**

When I wrote in the above that it did not work, I should have said the problem was a Mathematica "file not found" error, not a Python message saying that NumPy could not be imported.  Here is the environment information you requested:

```
StringSplit[Environment["PATH"], ";"] // Column
(*

 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Libraries\\Windows-x86-64",
 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Libraries\\Windows",
 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64",
 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.1",
 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64",
 "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64",
 "C:\\Windows\\system32",
 "C:\\Windows",
 "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem",
 "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"

*)
```

**My Python file**

I added code to the Python script to print the environment variable PATH, so here is my script:

`try :
      import os
      print(os.environ["PATH"])
    except :
      print("no import os, or no PATH")
    try :
      import numpy as np
      b = np.array([1,2,3])
      print(b)
    except :
      a = "jello world"
      print(a)`

**Mathematica evaluation**

You will note that IntelPython3 has added two path elements at the beginning of the path:

```
RunProcess[{"C:\\IntelPython3\\python.exe", "Python Scripts\\simple.py"}]
(*
<|"ExitCode" -> 0,
 "StandardOutput" ->
  "C:\\IntelPython3\\Library\\bin;C:\\IntelPython3\\DLLs;C:\\Program \
Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Libraries\\Windows-x86-64;C:\
\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Libraries\\Windows;C:\\\
Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64;C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1;C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64;C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Binaries\\Windows-\
x86-64;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;\
C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\

  [1 2 3]

  ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
*)
```

Comment: Thank you LouisB. But I tried to provide the full path to python before, it doesn't work. Would you please provide your result of `Environment["PATH"]`? I want to see if I missed something before.