# How to register Anaconda3(Python3.7) as external evaluator enviroment?

Tags: external-calls, python

I have installed [Anaconda3](https://www.anaconda.com/) (version 5.3.1 for Windows with Python 3.7, 64-bit) as the Python working enviroment, but when trying to register it as an external evaluator, it `RegisterExternalEvaluator` fails.

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"]

RegisterExternalEvaluator::invalid: -- Message text not found -- (ExternalEvaluate`Private`reason)
```

Mathematica can only can find the Python evaluator installed by `SystemInstall["Python"]`, but I need to use the Anaconda version.

Comment: Please eliminate the trivial issues, make sure you follow the documentation precisely, and if it still does not work, then fully update/rewrite the question (don't just comment), including all relevant information (what did you do, what happened e.g. errors messages, what did you expect to happen)

Comment: I am getting a failure (providing the path to the executable) with `RegisterExternalEvaluator::invalid: -- Message text not found -- (ExternalEvaluate`Private`reason)`.

Comment: See the workflow [Configure Python For ExternalEvaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) in the documentation. If after following those instructions you still have an issue then see this post ([155821](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155821)).

Comment: I do not use Windows anymore so I don't know where Anaconda puts the python executable. Are you sure that the file `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"` exists?  Given the location of executables on other operating systems, that path looks a bit weird to me.

Comment: @Szabolcs The path checked again is correct on `Windows`, perhaps  `RegisterExternalEvaluator` is not compatible with Python 3.7 in Anaconda3 directory.

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/42342

Comment: @user6014 Thanks! I'll try by that offical answer.

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: Did you install pyzmq?

Comment: Yes, `pyzmq` was intalled via `pip` command.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12.1 and Anaconda 2020.02 with Python 3.7.7 on a Win10 system. RegisterExternalEvaluator[] still doesn't work, so I've created a second environment in Anaconda with Python 3.6.5 and pyzmq, zeromq, as well as json libraries installed. With that I could reproduce all steps described in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExecuteAPythonFileWithExternalEvaluate.html. So thanks to Jerry and Jake.

Comment: I have Python 3.7.3 from Anaconda running with MMA 12.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After two days of battling this problem on Windows10, with limited success (including full system reset), the problem was fixed from this link: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1975953

For posterity, the solution is

> With the help of Wolfram support team, I figured out how to get the
> conda work in MMA in windows.
>
> 1. conda's installation and library path is not in Mathematica's
>    default Path. So we need to manually add the path by:
>
> SetEnvironment[  "PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <>
> "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3"] (*for
> python executable*)
>
> SetEnvironment[  "PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <>
> "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin"]
> (*for pyzmq library*) just replace the path above with your own conda
> path.
>
> 2. (re-)Register the conda in MMA by:
>
> RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python",
> "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe"]
> again replace the path above with your own conda path.
>
> 3. Now the conda should work in Mathematica. You can check it by
>    FindExternalEvaluators["Python"] .

Answer (score 4):

On mac in 2022:

```
SetEnvironment["PATH"->Environment["PATH"]<>";"<>"/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/"];


RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/python"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After reinstalling `Anaconda` different versions many times, it comes true that `MMA` does not support registering  `Python3.7` as an external evaluator now, so if `Anaconda` chosen to be used, choose the right version is necessary [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe), `Anaconda3-5.2.0`, which integrated `Python3.6`, more versions could be found at the [archive site](https://repo.continuum.io/archive) .

When `Anaconda5.2` installed, follow the offical steps to make it.
see more [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/42342) and [help center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html).

Comment: I see no problems with Python 3.7 on macOS http://i.stack.imgur.com/yhuq9.png

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! I have no idea about ver.3.7  on MacOS, using Windows.

Comment: Have you asked WRI Support?

Comment: @Kuba Not yet. I just try to determine whether it's proper to work with Python in the notebook or not. The default method supported by `SystemInstall` is enough at the end.

Comment: I cannot get python 3.7.5 working in Mathematica 12.0 in Windows 10 too. So I create an environment of python 3.6 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MMA 12.0. After many attempts, I found that any version of Python could work on Windows 10 as long as you are not using anaconda-python. Just properly set the PATH to make sure you can properly install pyzmq. I also tried anaconda with python 3.7.3, but MMA just  could not recongnize it (though pyzmq is also installed).