# "ExternalLanguage" cell with ExternalSessionObject

Tags: external-calls, version-11.3

How do I configure new External Language Input cell (that appears when pressing `>`) to use my instance of Python? I'm aware of `ExternalEvaluate`, but is there a way to attach `ExternalSessionObject` to this cell:

[image]

Comment: @Edmund can you use a specific `ExternalSessionObject` in the `"ExternalLanguage"` cell? If it just uses `ExternalEvaluate["Python", ...]` then it won't use a cached session by default.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think you are correct. It is not clear how to attach a specific `ExternalSessionObject` to the notebook cell.  Withdrawing my close vote.

Comment: @Coolwater this isn't a duplicate as this is specifically how to use the new-in-11.3 feature of external input cells with a specific `ExternalSessionObject`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run python with package numpy in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155185/run-python-with-package-numpy-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has to be done at the stylesheet level and here's a way to do it. First we'll make a new `CellEvaluationFunction` that uses the `TaggingRules` to bind the `ExternalSessionObject`. Then we'll attach that to the `"ExternalLanguage"` cell. Here's the function:

```
currentCellExternalSessionEvaluate =
  Function[
   With[{ExternalEvaluate`FE`Private`cell = EvaluationCell[]},
    With[{ExternalEvaluate`FE`Private`sessions =
       Replace[
        CurrentValue[
         ExternalEvaluate`FE`Private`cell,
         {
          TaggingRules,
          "ExternalSessions"
           }
         ],
        Except[_?OptionQ] :>
         CurrentValue[
          EvaluationNotebook[],
          {
           TaggingRules,
           "ExternalSessions"
            },
          Replace[ExternalEvaluate`FE`$CellSessions,
           Except[_?OptionQ] -> <||>
           ]
          ]
        ]
      },
     Block[{ExternalEvaluate`FE`$CellSessions = 
        Association@ExternalEvaluate`FE`Private`sessions},
      FrontEnd`Private`ExternalLanguageCellEvaluationFunction[##]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Then we can add this to our stylesheet like so:

```
Get["http://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/StylesheetEdit.wl"]

StyleSheetEdit["ExternalLanguage", 
 CellEvaluationFunction -> currentCellExternalSessionEvaluate,
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]
```

And finally we'll start a session and bind it to our notebook:

```
myPy = FileNameJoin@{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Python", "config", 
    "python3.4", "bin", "python3"};

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
  {TaggingRules, "ExternalSessions", "Python"}
  ] = StartExternalSession[{"Python", "Executable" -> myPy}]
```

Then I can just call:

```python
import sys
print(sys.version)

3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 19 2015, 20:38:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
```

(somehow my `ExternalSessionObject` can't parse any results, but this is just proof of concept)

Then I can remove the binding:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
   {TaggingRules, "ExternalSessions", "Python"}
   ] = Inherited;
```

And it all works as normal:

```python
import sys
sys.version

2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
```

Note that the `TaggingRules` may also be applied to specific cells to make this more fine-tuned.

Comment: That's pretty sophisticated, but very cool!

Comment: This once worked but seems to have stopped. Somehow the `currentCellExternalSessionEvaluate` now shows a syntax error...

Comment: @b3m2a1 This is a very valuable answer, could you please update it when you can, I'm still sure why it's failing now in 12

Comment: @M.R. This seems to now be implemented via `EvaluationMode -> "ExternalLanguage"`. It's not clear to me that this is accessible anymore. I'd contact WRI to tell them to tell John Fultz that he fracked up a good thing.

Comment: @b3m2a1 See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236298/403) which works in 12.2

Answer (score 3):

There is a https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SetLanguageCellSession/ for some time already, and I've been using it to do this.