# Alternative for ExternalEvaluate in version <11.2

Tags: code-request, compatibility, external-calls

I have code which uses `ExternalEvaluate`. Specifically the format using `"Command"` and `"Arguments"` where the arguments automatically get converted to python input.

```
ExternalEvaluate[pythonSession1,<| "Command" -> "pythonCommand", 
                    "Arguments" -> {arg}|> ]
```

I now need to run this code on a cluster where only version 11.1 is available. Is there any work around to add a custom `externalEvaluate` that mimics the behavior of `ExternalEvaluate`.

Comment: I think you will need to do something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155225/9490)

Comment: I think that just runs a predetermined string in python. I might have to resort to something like this (at that point I think I prefer to just call python from the command line). So it skips the most useful and probably the hardest part of  passing the Mathematica arguments to a python function. I would love it if someone knows a way to handle that automatically like `ExternalEvaluate` does.

Comment: For that matter. I have seen that some people manage to extract Mathematica definitions. Is there any hope of reconstructing ExternalEvaluate by extracting its definitions from a future version and doing a sort of "Future Import"?

Comment: I tried whether I could follow the build in definitions to an argument converting function using https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/45020, I think that the thread leading to `ExternalEvaluate\`Private\`normalizeMessage` is the relevant one but I got lost there without finding out how the argument conversion works.