# How to reconstruct a complicated built-in function (e.g. for modification or use in a version that does not have it yet)

Tags: function-construction, code-request, built-in-symbols

Is it possible to extract the definitions for a built-in function to reconstruct a similar user defined function. This would be useful to port new mathematica functionality to older versions or to create modified versions of built-in functions.

I found that

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[symbol];
```

could get us close (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/45020) but it would still be quite a job to reconstruct the full function including all of its dependencies from there. Have there been any automated attempts to try this kind of thing?

As an example I would be very interesting in reconstructing `ExternalEvaluate` (or if that is too ambitious to reconstruct only the part that converts Mathematica arguments supplied with `"Arguments"->{args}` to python expressions in the case that we `ExternalEvaluate` using a python session.)

(I hope this type of question is not frowned upon in light of copyright issues. I would just like to deal with incompatibility issues between different (Licensed) versions of Mathematica.)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Alternative for ExternalEvaluate in version <11.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250294/alternative-for-externalevaluate-in-version-11-2)

Comment: One issue is that many functions are implemented all or partly in C or C++. For functions written entirely in top-level code, it might be feasible although, as noted in the question, getting the dependencies all sorted out can be daunting.

Comment: Rather that ask essentially the same question as your [250294](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/250294/1063) but with a bit more information, just edit your original question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, okay. I thought they were different enough. With the other one there is a completely different direction that does not involve extracting built-in functions which is an interesting topic on its own. Of course when I included the same example function to reconstruct the question became quite similar.